# Is there an alternative to map to apply a function to all in the sequence in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a function

```
(defn change-score [docid termid]
    (do (dosync (alter *documents-scores* assoc docid  (+ 1 (*documents-scores* docid))))
            nil)  )

(defn vector-space[]
    (loop [terms (count (deref *term-hash*))]
        (if (zero? terms)
            nil
            (do
                (dorun (map (fn[docid](change-score docid terms)) (doc-list terms)))
                (recur (dec terms))))))
```

Is there an alternative to map in the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[doseq](http://clojure.org/api#toc222) is precisely for this purpose.

```
(doseq [x xs] (side-effect x))
```

Comment: As somebody who's just started looking at Clojure (and liking it a lot), I have to say that the linked documentation for doseq is not that clear.  Is it referring to how things are done in the for form?  If so, the doc for that one could be better, too (best thing about for's doc is the example.)

Comment: Yup, there is a wiki with examples which you might find handy:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/API_Examples/do_Macros#doseq